# How to initialize c3po connection pool on application launch?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, c3p0

`c3p0` connection pool initialize when I perform some `JPA` operation, it takes 2 seconds to initialize.

```
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">30</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">150</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.privilegeSpawnedThreads">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
```

So is there a way to do it on application launch?

Answer (score 1):

Perform an operation on application startup.

If your c3p0 `DataSource` is called `myPool`, then `myPool.getConnection().close()` is sufficient.

Comment: I've configured it in hibernate.cfg so is it possible working with hibernate.cfg? I mean DataSource with existing connection configured in hibernate.cfg .